# "There are two kinds of people" quote

Tags: identify-this-movie, dialogue

I'm trying to remember the title of a movie that had this quote (or something very similar) in it, can anyone help?

> "there are two kinds of people in this world, those who bend facts to fit beliefs, and those who bend beliefs to fit facts".

Comment: The one I know is "there are twu types of people in the world, those who come through the door, and those who come through the window"

Comment: The "two kinds of people"-meme seems to be quite old. I find that this one from [The Good, the Bad and the Ugly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060196/) fits well to the question: "You see, in this world there's two kinds of people, my friend: Those with loaded guns and those who dig. You dig." `:-)`

Comment: I didn't find it but have a look in these: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThereAreTwoKindsOfPeopleInTheWorld http://danspira.com/meme-collection/there-are-two-kinds-of-people-in-the-world-those-who-think-there-are-two-kinds-of-people-in-the-world-and-those-who-dont/ http://www.subzin.com/search.php?q=two+of+people+in+this+world

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Sherlock Holmes (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0988045/)

> **Sherlock Holmes:** [to Watson] Never theorize before you have data. Invariably, you end up twisting facts to suit theories, instead of theories to suit facts.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of, thanks a lot! Haha I'm kind of surprised I didn't realize this before, I'm a pretty big Holmes fan. Thanks!

Comment: I happened to stumble across the original book quote and remembered this question. _It is a capital mistake to theorize before you have all the evidence. It biases the judgment._ ([WikiQuote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes)).